# Add OR condition on getDbCriteria

Tags: yii

I need to add an `OR` condition to my query.

like `or t.offline is null`.

I have this.

```
public function isOffline($offline = 'fales')
{
    $this->getDbCriteria()->mergeWith(array(
        'condition'=>"t.offline=$offline",
    ));

    return $this;
}
```

How can add this?

Answer (score 1):

You can just use

```
$this->getDbCriteria()->mergeWith(array(
    'condition'=>"t.offline=$offline OR t.offline is null",
));
```